# How do I scrape price/tax history table in zillow?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
#import urllib2
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.zillow.com/homes/recently_sold/Culver-City-CA/house,condo,apartment_duplex,townhouse_type/20432063_zpid/51617_rid/12m_days/globalrelevanceex_sort/34.048605,-118.340178,33.963223,-118.47785_rect/12_zm/")
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("collapsible-header").click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

region = soup.find("div",{"id":"hdp-price-history"})
table = region.find('table',{'class':'zsg-table yui3-toggle-content-minimized'})
print table
```

I try to scrape tax/table price in zillow, but the result I get is None. How do I get that table?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following uses `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` to get the data, no selenium required (and so is fast).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0"}    
r = requests.get("https://www.zillow.com/homes/recently_sold/Culver-City-CA/house,condo,apartment_duplex,townhouse_type/20432063_zpid/51617_rid/12m_days/globalrelevanceex_sort/34.048605,-118.340178,33.963223,-118.47785_rect/12_zm/", headers=headers)
urls = re.findall(re.escape('AjaxRender.htm?') + '(.*?)"', r.content)
url = "https://www.zillow.com/AjaxRender.htm?{}".format(urls[4])
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content.replace('\\', ''), "html.parser")
data = []

for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
    data.append([td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')])

for row in data[:5]:        # Show first 5 entries    
    print row
```

This shows the first 5 entries are:

```
[u'06/16/17', u'Sold', u'$940,000-0.9%', u'K. Miller, A. Masket', u'']
[u'06/14/17', u'Price change', u'$949,000-1.0%', u'', u'']
[u'05/08/17', u'Pending sale', u'$959,000', u'', u'']
[u'04/17/17', u'Price change', u'$959,000+1.1%', u'', u'']
[u'02/27/17', u'Pending sale', u'$949,000', u'', u'']
```

The required HTML is not present in the first GET but it generated on demand when the `Price / Tax History` section is expanded. This triggers an AJAX request in a browser. The codes searches for all of these requests in the initial HTML and makes the same request. The fourth such request is used to get the required section. The HTML that is returned needs `\` to be removed and can then be passed to BeautifulSoup for parsing as a table.

Comment: you help me a lot! Thanks so much !

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to click on the grey tick under the up/down buttons to select an answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use BeautifulSoup. You can get required table with below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.zillow.com/homes/recently_sold/Culver-City-CA/house,condo,apartment_duplex,townhouse_type/20432063_zpid/51617_rid/12m_days/globalrelevanceex_sort/34.048605,-118.340178,33.963223,-118.47785_rect/12_zm/")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "collapsible-header"))).click()
table = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#hdp-price-history table.zsg-table.yui3-toggle-content-minimized")))
print(table.text)
```

Required table generated dinamically, so you need to wait some time until its presence in DOM. That's why you can't find table in page source right after click